# Windows Version (Unable to confirm if installed Windows version is 10 or greater) in Flutter?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I was trying to install flutter, I did all the procedure for android studio but now the "Windows Version (Unable to confirm if installed Windows version is 10 or greater)" issue appear, anybody knows how to solve this? I have W10.

Answer (score 0):

i found this answer in another forum
i have the same problem but my app works just fine
try this :

```
flutter clean
```

....

flutter downgrade 1.6.3 or (1.6.6)

...

flutter channel stable

...

flutter upgrade

..

Then the editor will ask to do flutter packages get

and finally we do `flutter run` .

You can run the project as debug from the home file (optional).

Answer (score -1):

to know if flutter is installed
run the `flutter` command in the cmd (Command line) :

```
flutter
```

and if you want to know the version:

```
flutter -v
```

and if you have installed the required tools to use flutter without problem :

```
flutter doctor
```